# Is it possible to use Medium.com functionality on my own website?

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

I have seen several websites that seem to extend medium.com functionality for the blog section. i.e.
https://blog.signals.network/sale-ends-today-at-14-00-utc-what-will-be-next-bb94e740853e

I cannot seem to find out how it's done. Their API returns JSON so I'm wondering if this site is building a page to look like medium.com or if there's an easier way to do it.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: from where do you need the feeds? from Publications or from  user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, now it is not possible, as medium said "*As of November 2017, Medium is no longer offering new custom domains as a feature. Instead, you can create a publication on Medium that will live on a medium.com/publication-name URL.*"

Reference URL: https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003053487-Custom-Domains-service-deprecation